# How to add a new line when writing to a text file?

Tags: java

So my code basically asks the user to enter an integer and that integer is saved into a file by writing it. However, when I want to add another integer, it just replaces the previous integer entered. How do I add the new integer in file without replacing the previous one?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File file = new File("Text.txt");
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(fw);

    int steps = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many steps"));

    writer.println(steps);

    writer.close();

    }
```

Comment: Open in append mode. [Write to text file without overwriting in Java](//stackoverflow.com/q/9961292)

Comment: You just need `new FileWriter(file, true);` to append Files instead of overwriting

Comment: Please read the javadoc before posting such questions,

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter(java.io.File,%20boolean)

Comment: Your question is not about how to add a newline, it is about how to append to s file.

Answer (score 1):

You must initialize your `FileWriter` object in 'append' mode, by sending `true` parameter.

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file , true)
```

Comment: The parameter `true` is a boolean.